# How can I duplicate tabPage in c#?

Tags: c#, copy, duplicates, tabcontrol

How can I duplicate a "tabPage" inside of my TabControl?

I tried this:

```
   //My TabControl: tc
   //My Tab ID: 0
   TabPage newPage = new TabPage();

   foreach (Control control in tc.TabPages[0].Controls)
   {
      newPage.Controls.Add(control);
   }
   tc.TabPages.Add(newPage);
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to _copy_ all of the controls.  This is not simple; consider moving them to a UserControl.

Comment: @SLaks, I'm looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507173/copy-tabcontrol-tab) article, it's a right way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got it!

For those who has the same kind of problem, Here is what I’ve done:

I had created a UserControl (thanks a lot for @SLaks and @Brian for your tip), copied all objects from my TabControl to my new UserControl and used the follow code to create a dynamic tabs:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
   UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
   TabPage tp = new TabPage();
   tp.Controls.Add(uc);
   this.TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
}
```

Comment: Very cice solution with use of `UserControl` (that I didn't know of) I was doing something similar but with panels.

Comment: is tabpage is declared outside?

Answer (score 2):

As Schabse mentioned in a comment above, I *highly* recommend that you do this with [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).