# Passing with ref keyword

Tags: c#

I have 2 tab pages (tabA and tabB) within a main form. Say I pass `tabA` into `tabB` at the main form initalization:

```
tabB = new TabB(tabA);
```

So what i observe is that after changing a value inside `tabA` (say `tabA.Text`) , the value inside `tabB` (`tabB.tabA.Text`) changes as well.

So my understanding (from C++) is that this is similar to pass-by-reference. So my question is what is the difference if I write this instead?

```
tabB = new TabB(ref tabA);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your analogy to C++ is incorrect. Passing reference objects<sup>*</sup> in C# is similar to passing objects by pointer in C++, with the exception that C# does not require an asterisk to dereference these pointers.

Passing by reference in C# would be similar to passing a pointer by reference in C++: in addition to using that pointer inside your function, you would also be able to assign a new value to it, thus changing the value of the pointer in the caller.

Here is a short illustration:

```
void One(List<int> list) {
    // Reassignment of the list is local to method One
    list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
}
void Two(ref List<int> list) {
    // Reassignment of the list is visible in the caller
    list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
}
...
var demo = new List<int> {5, 6, 7};
One(demo);
// Here the list remains [5, 6, 7]
Two(ref demo);
// Here the list becomes [1, 2, 3]
```

<sup>*</sup> As opposed to value objects, such as `struct`s and primitives, which are copied.

Comment: exactly what I was thinking!

Answer (score 1):

The difference would be, that if you changed the *object pointed to* by `tabA` argument in `TabB` constructor, `tabA` would use the new object too.

There actually isn't a way to pass the object itself, but you may do a copy / clone, which would look just like the original. There has already been written [a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10267292/948909) for the general case of copying a windows control, and [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14507314/948909) for the tabs only.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that by using the `ref` keyword you can change the reference itself, not just the object being pointed to by the reference.

```
void funcA(TabA tabA)
{
   // setting tabA to null here has no effect outside this function
   tabA = null;
}

void funcB(ref TabA tabA)
{
   // setting tabA to null persists outside this function
   // and changes the actual reference passed in.
   tabA = null;
}

// tabA initialized to non-null
tabA = new TabA();

funcA(tabA);

// tabA is still not null

funcB(ref tabA);

// tabA is now null
```