# WinForm - Copy TabControl with OWN behaviour

Tags: c#, duplicates, copy, tabcontrol

[Copy TabControl Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507173/copy-tabcontrol-tab) Yes I have checked this.

I'm trying to duplicate a tabcontol but this tab should have it's own 'behaviour'.

```
        TabControl tc = TC_Fields;
        TabPage tpOld = tc.TabPages[0];

        TabPage tpNew = new TabPage();

        fields += 1;
        tpNew.Name = "Field_" + fields;
        tpNew.Text = "Field-" + fields;

        foreach (Control c in tpOld.Controls)
        {
            Control cNew = (Control) Activator.CreateInstance(c.GetType());
            PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(c);
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor entry in pdc)
            {
                object val = entry.GetValue(c);
                if (entry.Name == "Name")
                {
                    val = (String) val + fields;    
                }
                entry.SetValue(cNew, val);
            }
            tpNew.Controls.Add(cNew);
        }

        tc.TabPages.Add(tpNew);
```

I've tried above code, so it gives the new control a new "id", yet I am still not able to click the controls in the new tab, and they only mimic what's in the first tab.

Is there a way I can copy all controls yet not mimic the controls they were copied of?

Comment: Do you mean that the new  controls do the same as the old ones or that they do no do anything at all?? I don't think any event handlers get copied; so you need to write new ones (obviously) and then hook them up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code has at least two issues not related to the actual question. Let's fix two of them first:

   - You set all properties even those you should not set; most notably you should not touch the `"WindowTarget"` property! It is for internal use only and messing with it will stop at least some controls from working. I found I couldn't check a `CheckBox`, for example.
   - Your code only will create **visible** controls if the orginal `TabPage` is also the **current** one. All controls on all other pages are invisible and if you try to clone any other `TabPage` all control will be added just fine but remain **invisible**.

Let's add a filter :

```
if(entry.Name != "WindowTarget")     entry.SetValue(cNew, val);
```

and make the new controls visible:

```
cNew.Visible = true;
tpNew.Controls.Add(cNew);
```

Note that this is a simplistic solution as it will also make those controls visible that were invisible originally. You could instead show the page you want to clone or make a list of invisible controls; with their names you could find the cloned counterparts..

The last issue is also important but goes beyond the question: The code only clones the controls directly on the page, not any neseted controls (like `RadioButtons` in a `GroupBox` !). To do so you would have to write a **recursive** version!

2. Now for the actual question: How can you give the cloned controls their own behaviour?

After cloning all their properties they are like freshly added controls, i.e. they have **no event handlers at all**.

So you need to

- write new event handlers for the new controls' events
- hook them up

While this is not really hard there are quite a few problems..

We know the naming scheme and so we can know which controls we want to supply with events. The event names are free to choose but to hook them up we need to know which of the new controls we are dealing with..

Here is and example that hooks up the **first** clone of a `Button cb_hello` with a `Click` event:

```
  if (cNew.Name == "cb_hello1") cNew.Click += buttonNew_Click;
```

The code in the event demonstrates more issues:

```
private void buttonNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    Console.WriteLine(btn.Name + " says hiho");
    btn.Parent.Controls["panel41"].BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
    ((RadioButton)btn.Parent.Controls["radioButton11"]).Checked = true;  
}
```

While casting the `sender` to `Button` is quite normal we run into trouble when we try to access any of the controls we have just cloned:

- Since they were dynamically created we can't access any of them with variables. Instead we need to use the `TabPage`'s `Controls` collection to find them.
- We can set `BackColor` or any other property inherited from `Control` but to set `RadioButton.Checked` we need to cast to `RadioButton`; and we need to access the control from the `Controls` collection, for example by its `Name`.
- Once you upgrade to [recursive cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473597/it-is-possible-to-copy-all-the-properties-of-a-certain-control-c-window-forms/44282304#44282304) you will want to use `Controls.Find(name, true)` to include the nested controls..

As you can see it can be done but it will take a little more effort than coding the original controls and the code feels somewhat fragile as we introduce hidden dependencies: All those references to the **cloned** names rely on the **original** names!

Final note: While the regular properiets get cloned, the `data` and `structure` containers do not, i.e. all `Items`, `ListViewItems` or `Rows`, `Columns` collections etc, etc are **not** cloned!

Answer (score 0):

```
        TabControl tc = TC_Fields;
        TabPage tpOld = tc.SelectedTab;

        TabPage tpNew = new TabPage();

        fields += 1;
        tpNew.Name = "Field_" + fields;
        tpNew.Text = "Field-" + fields;

        foreach (Control c in tpOld.Controls)
        {
            Control cNew = (Control) Activator.CreateInstance(c.GetType());
            PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(c);
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor entry in pdc)
            {
                object val = entry.GetValue(c);
                if (entry.Name == "Name")
                {
                    val = (String) val + fields;
                }
                else if (entry.Name == "Location" || entry.Name == "Text" || entry.Name == "Bounds" || entry.Name == "Enabled" 
                    || entry.Name == "Visible" || entry.Name == "Checked" || entry.Name == "CheckState")
                {
                    //Nothing to do, but do continue!
                }
                else if (entry.Name == "Controls")
                {
                    Control.ControlCollection controllsInside = (Control.ControlCollection) val;
                    foreach (Control controllInside in controllsInside)
                    {
                        Control cNewInside = (Control) Activator.CreateInstance(controllInside.GetType());
                        PropertyDescriptorCollection pdcInside = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(controllInside);
                        foreach (PropertyDescriptor entryInside in pdcInside)
                        {
                            object valInside = entryInside.GetValue(controllInside);
                            if (entryInside.Name == "Name")
                            {
                                valInside = (String) valInside + fields;
                            }
                            else if (entryInside.Name == "Location" || entryInside.Name == "Text" || entryInside.Name == "Bounds" || entryInside.Name == "Enabled" 
                                || entryInside.Name == "Visible" || entryInside.Name == "Checked" || entryInside.Name == "CheckState")
                            {
                                //Nothing to do, but do continue!
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            entryInside.SetValue(cNewInside, valInside);
                        }
                        cNew.Controls.Add(cNewInside);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
                entry.SetValue(cNew, val);
            }
            tpNew.Controls.Add(cNew);
        }

        tc.TabPages.Add(tpNew);
        TC_Fields.SelectedIndex = fields - 1;
```

This will also do the trick :) @TaW already put the solution on there, but here is some copy paste code :)